# does NH4OH lose concentration when it is open?

Tags: titration, evaporation

I get a lot of variation on NH4OH titration and I am curious if anyone knows if NH4OH at concentration greater than 20% will evaporate the NH3 and decrease in concentration if it is open and at room temp. 20c

Comment: Of course it will. That's how you feel its smell, BTW.

Comment: Avoid using $\ce{NH4OH}$ formula, it is the old and wrong way to describe  the ammonia solution. It does not exist in water solutions either in non dissociated form, either ( in majority ) as  ions $\ce{NH4+(aq)}$ and $\ce{OH-(aq)}$. $\ce{OH-}$ is a strong base, while $\ce{NH4+}$ is a weak acid, mutually reacting as $\ce{NH4+(aq) + OH-(aq) <=>>NH3(aq) + H2O(aq)}$.

Comment: NH4OH does not exist.

Comment: My PI when I was doing my PhD told this hilarious story from his time as a student when another student was tricked into getting solid $\ce{NH4OH}$ from another lab. The lab assistant sent her, not thinking she would do it (it was for her own experiment), then quickly called the person he sent her to, telling him to give her the correct chemical but label it $\ce{NH4OH}$ (solid). By the time she came back, he had supplied everyone else with beer and declared the lab day over.

Answer (score 3):

As by the comment by Ivan Neretin «of course it [i.e., an aqueous solution of $\ce{NH4OH}$] will [lose concentration if exposed openly to air]».  Because an aqueous solution of ammonia mostly is ammonia *physically* soluted in water ([example](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/ed018p29)) just as observed with other gases like oxygen, nitrogen, carbon dioxide, too.

Of course you may write the chemical equilibrium of

$$ \ce{NH3 + H2O <<=> NH4+ + OH-}$$

however, as already indicated by the arrow, the corresponding equilibrium constant is small. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia_solution)

$$K_b = \frac{[\ce{NH4+}] [\ce{OH−}]} {[\ce{NH3}]} = 1.8 × 10^{−5}$$

corresponding to about 0.42% of ammonium in a 1M aqueous solution of ammonia.  Thus, it is only a matter of time of exposure to air and the temperature of the solution until ammonia is evaporated.

A second reason why aqueous solutions of ammonia become less concentrated over time is their reaction with $\ce{CO2}$ of air. If the concentration of ammonia is high enough, you may see this next to the mouth of the bottle, too.  Because it can build up a solid deposit literally baking the stop cocks of glass bottles like seen for lye like $\ce{NaOH}$, on occasion you may see rubber plugs being used instead of stop cocks made of glass to close flasks of $\pu{250 mL}$ volume and smaller.  But compared to $\ce{NaOH}$, this issue is of smaller importance.